# Interface builder iOS 5 compability trouble

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface

I have unknown before problem with IB.
I'm creating navigation bar in my IB, but if y of it equals 20 it looks good at the iOS 4, but on the iOS 5 - not.

**Screenshots.**
[image: Interface Builder]

***IB***

[image: iOS 5]
***iOS 5***

[image: iOS 4.3.3]
***iOS 4.3.3***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that the view in iOS 5 does not have a Status Bar enabled. Enable a Status Bar in the view and the problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the y value of the navigation bar to 20? Users expect to see the nav bar at the very top. Having a space between the top between the navigation bar is jarring.

If you set the y to 0 then it should be flush with the top across iOS 4.3 and 5.0

Comment: No, it will be under status bar in iOS 4.3

Answer (score 0):

In the `project-Info.plist` add `Status bar is initially hidden = YES`

But the view's Y still set 20 , not 0